# How to resize browser's window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is jQuery event handler for windows resize.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
// code here
});
```

Is it possible to resize current window of browser using jQuery or JavaScript?

What I am doing now is, open window in new screen like following:

```
window.open('http://google.com?screenWidth=400,left=10,top=10,resizable=no');
```

I want to resize in current browser rather than new windows.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: The question you give link that you thought same but NOT, what I want is to do this even via jQuery.